# React Router with Asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, react-router

I am trying to use React router with asp.net core. The problem is that I can't access the Blog component.

Here's the error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Here's my code:

**webpack.config.js**

```
    const path = require('path');
    const webpack = require('webpack');
    module.exports = {
    entry: { 'main':'./Client/index.js'},
    output: {
    path:path.resolve(__dirname,'wwwroot/dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: 'dist/'
    },
    watch: true,
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
    rules: [ 
    {test: /\.css$/, use: [{ loader: "style-loader" },
    { loader: "css-loader" }]},
    { test: /\.js?$/, 
    use: { loader: 'babel-loader', options: { presets: 
                  ['@babel/preset-react','@babel/preset-env'] } } },
      ]
    }
   }
```

index.js from client side. I am fully aware that asp.net core has template for react application. I just don't like to use typescript

**index.js**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
    import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
    import ReduxPromise from 'redux-promise'
    import reducers from './reducers';
    import Blog from './components/Blog';
    import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
    import { BrowserRouter,Route } from 'react-router-dom'
    import './style/index.css'
    import App from './components/App';
    const store = applyMiddleware(ReduxPromise)(createStore);
    ReactDom.render(
    <Provider store={store(reducers)}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
       <NavBar/>
        //Can't access this Component
       <Route exact path='/blog' component={Blog}/> 
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   </Provider>
   ,document.getElementById('react-app')
  )
```

**Startup.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
    namespace server
   {
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {   
                HotModuleReplacement = true,
                ReactHotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Have you setup View correctly?

Comment: Forgot to mention, the NavBar is visible on '/' but when I redirect to '/blog' both of the components doesn't shows up

Comment: I am also facing the same issue

Comment: did you try my answer ?

Answer (score 9):

Turns out, I just need to add this to **Startup.cs**

```
    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
    name: "spa-fallback",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: You saved my life! Can you also refer to the source?

Comment: See [what-is-equivalent-to-mapspafallbackroute-for-asp-net-core-3-0-endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57822513/3773983) for .net core 3.

Answer (score 1):

I too have the same issue with the new frameworks but turn out to be above solution works below the 3.0 framework.
Below is the way for above frameworks

**ASP.NET Core MVC 3.0+**

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");
```

**ASP.NET Core MVC Before 3.0**

```
routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
   name: "spa-fallback",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```