# What is equivalent to `MapSpaFallbackRoute` for ASP.NET Core 3.0 endpoints?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

In ASP.NET Core 2.x I used standard routes registation `Configure` method of `Startup` class to **register fallback route** for SPA application using `MapSpaFallbackRoute` extension method from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions` Nuget package:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    // ...
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
}
```

I cannot find similar extension method when using ASP.NET Core 3.0 recommended `UseEndpoints` extension method for endpoints registration.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core 3.0 extension method `MapFallbackToController` has same functionality to `MapSpaFallbackRoute` extension method.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");
    });
}
```

Comment: Are these alternative lines or both necessary?

Comment: Maybe I can put it this way: as long as MVC has a way to resolve route for `HomeController`'s `Index` method, which is our fallback, `endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");` will work.

Answer (score 3):

This decision helped me!

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application)
{
    application
        // other extensions...
        .UseEndpoints(endpoints => endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute())
        .UseSpa(_ => { }); // extension from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions' assembly
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation and details to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me out when upgrading from 2.1 to 3.1 aspnetcore3.1

```
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "api",
                pattern: "api/{controller=Default}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
                );

            endpoints.MapFallbackToController("Index", "Home");
        }).UseSpa(_ => { _.Options.DefaultPage = "spa-fallback"; }); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 7 add it to program.cs file as below:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
});
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/aspnet-core/7.0/fallback-file-endpoints#recommended-action