# Cannot navigate to react component with route via browser address line

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my `App.jsx` file:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Content} />
      <Route path="/login" component={Auth} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

And everything works, I can redirect to these routes via `<Redirect />` then I can go back via browser back button but I can't get to concrete component via browser address line. If I type 'localhost:5000/login' I get 404 error. So how to go to certain component via browser address line?

**ADDED**
This is my `Auth` component that decides what auth form to render `Login` or `Register`:

```
export default class Auth extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoginActive: true,
    };

    this.formChange = this.formChange.bind(this);
  }

  formChange() {
    this.setState({ isLoginActive: !this.state.isLoginActive });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoginActive } = this.state;

    let view = isLoginActive ? (
      <Login apiUrl={apiUrl} formChange={this.formChange} history={this.props.history} />
    ) : (
      <Register apiUrl={apiUrl} formChange={this.formChange} history={this.props.history} />
    );

    return (
      <div className="container">
        {getCookie("token") == null ? view : <Redirect to="/" />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And here is my `Login` component

```
export default class Login extends React.Component {
  //constructor

  login() {
    // axios request
    this.setState({ userLoggedIn: true });
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.userLoggedIn ? (
      <Redirect to="/" />
    ) : (
      <div className="base-container">
          <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.login}>
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to launch default react-router example and it didn't work for me:

```
export default function BasicExample() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/about">
              <About />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/dashboard">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
  
  function Home() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Home bla</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  function About() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>About</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  function Dashboard() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

May be the problem is that I develop the react app with ASP Core back-end and there is some restrictions?

Comment: Where are you rendering a `Redirect` component? Can you provide a more comprehensive code example? I see no issue/reason why you shouldn't be able to directly access "/login".

Comment: Added more info

Comment: Seems you've redacted some code, can you create a *running* codesandbox that accurately reproduces the issue you see?

Answer (score 0):

try to console the userLoggedIn in login page. Might be it is undefined for firs time. change the userLoggedIn to a prop and send it from auth to the login page.

```
  render() {
    return this.state.userLoggedIn ? (
      <Redirect to="/" />
    ) : (
      <div className="base-container">
          <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={this.login}>
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. The problem was in ASP Core 3 that I use with my React application. I found the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57822512/what-is-equivalent-to-mapspafallbackroute-for-asp-net-core-3-0-endpoints) and it helped me.
Sorry I didn't notice ASP I've just didn't pay attention it can be important =) Thanks everybody for help